# Tree/Graph Traversal: Find maximum value path

Tags: java, algorithm, search, graph, tree

I'm attempting to, given a graph G with integer values and N levels, sum the values from the root to a leaf node. Find the maximal sum of these path values. Children nodes can have multiple parents, thats why its more a graph than a tree.

For example,

[image]

I tried implementing this via BFS for a small Java applet, but I'm not sure that was the best way. Are there other suggestions to keep this to scale with the number of nodes, i.e. O(n). I can't think of any way that scales to O(n). Any ideas?

Comment: If the graph has pyramid form as above, then you can propagate the maximum sum from the deepest node to the root node.

Comment: Is the graph directed? Can your there be cycles?

Comment: ALMOST a Tree, except the fact that multiple parents are allowed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this in linear time by using a dynamic programming algorithm to propagate the information from the nodes in the bottom layer upward.

Think about it this way: if the graph has just one layer, then the optimal answer must be to just take the biggest value from that layer.  On the other hand, suppose that the graph has n + 1 layers and assume that you've (recursively) computed the optimal solution for the bottommost n layers.  In that case, you can find the optimal solution overall by looking at the top layer and computing, for each entry, the sum of that entry plus the optimal solution for any of its direct children (which you've already precomputed).  The maximum value out of all of these then gives you the overall maximum value.

This approach ends up visiting every edge exactly once, so the total runtime ends up being O(n + m), where n is the number of nodes and m the number of edges.

Hope this helps!

Comment: but this won't work in some cases, unless i'm mistaken. for example, what if the second layer had all 0's except for one which had 1. but from a 0-node, a value of 100 was there which the 1 couldn't get to. your algo would take the path down 1, while taking the path down the 0 would be best.

Comment: @kpscript- I think the algorithm works in this case.  You don't compute the algorithm top-down (since, as you've seen, it won't always work), but instead go bottom-up.  As a result, when you're computing the values in the top layer, you use as your values for the layer below it the values you've computed before.  This means that if there's a 0 leading to an 100, you would have precomputed that this 0 actually has value 100.  You would then detect this when scanning the top level and looking one layer below.  Does that make sense?